# UIImageView v/s Drawing from code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, image

I'm developing an app that must show one of three shapes(UIImageViews) depending on which button the user taps. I'm achieving this by creating different UIImageViews with three UIImages. I was wondering, is it more efficient if I draw the shapes directly from code?? 
BTW, the images have transparency and are 342 px x 388 px. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the shapes. I suggest using PNG image files unless you are having particular speed issues. This lets the designers/artists customize the look easily rather than making the programmers do it in code, which is more tedious to modify.

We have some nice gradients and shadows in our application and drawing them using Quartz was pretty slow -- fine for a single screen, but too slow when animated or scrolled.